# UserForm VBA Excel - Function Match

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to make a simple userform in Excel by VBA Code.
The main function looks for a number and displays the values associated with it.
For example:
If my input is 1 (TextBox), then it should find this: Worksheet "db", Cell(1, 2)
this is the second day I have spent on this now and it is still not working. I guess the problem is with the Range value.

My code:

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim RecordRow As Long
    Dim RecordRange As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    RecordRow = Application.Match(CLng(TextBox1.Value), Sheets("db").Range("B:B"), 0)
    
    Set RecordRange = Sheets("db").Range("B:G").Cells(1, 1).Offset(RecordRow - 1, 0)
    TextBox2.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value
    TextBox3.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 2).Value
    TextBox4.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 3).Value
    TextBox5.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 4).Value
        
End Sub
```

Could you support me, please?

Comment: Formatted code is soooo much easier to read AND review. Personally, `match` is obsolete to `find`. I suggest looking at https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-find/ And lastly, if you use error codes, ensure you know how/what/when to use. In this instance, you should check to see if a match or find has been found.

Comment: @alowflyingpig in no way is `Match` obsolete to `Find` .  Sure, there is overlap in their use, but for single column or row lookups `Match` is by far the better option.  (You _coukd_ argue `Applicatio.Match` has been superceded by `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` or even `XMatch`, but that's a different argument)

Comment: @alowflyingpig `Worksheet.Match` is much better than `Find`. Please delete that comment so as to NOT confuse people trying to learn!

Comment: Thanks for your support. I fixed my code and Match is working. But the problem was not in code but type of value. I want to find a very long numbers. Normally, I set format calls as "Text" but this is a problem for VBA.

Comment: @chrisneilsen hence the preface "personally". I find (unintended pun) that `.Find` is more user-friendly and easier to manipulate. Agreed that they are both not obsolete and have their own uses in situations.

Comment: @alowflyingpig FWIW my comment was about the use of "obsolete".  Obsolete and personal preference are two very different things.  Speaking of personal preference,  I try to avoid Find simply because it modifies the default settings,  which I find very annoying when I go back to the manual Find dialog and have to reset settings again

Answer (score 1):

If a match is not found `Application.Match` doesn't through a runtime error, it returns a error value.  So, remove the OERN, return the match to a Variant and test for `IsError`

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim RecordRow As Variant

    RecordRow = Application.Match(CLng(TextBox1.Value), Sheets("db").Range("B:B"), 0)
    If Not IsError(RecordRow) Then
        With Sheets("db").Cells(RecordRow, 2)
            TextBox2.Value = .Offset(0, 1).Value
            TextBox3.Value = .Offset(0, 2).Value
            TextBox4.Value = .Offset(0, 3).Value
            TextBox5.Value = .Offset(0, 4).Value
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I fixed my code and simple query are processed correctly. But the problem is type of intput. I have no problem with simple numbers like 1234567. But if I want to find some text or a very long number - is not possible (Error 13 - mismatch).

Comment: You are casting your Textbox value (which can only be a string) to `Long`.  If the user enters a "number" that's out of range of long you will get that error.  You also say _if I want to find some text ..._ . To handle user entered text, you can't use `CLng`.  Sounds to me you need to reevaluate your design

Comment: Once again the true & important hint to avoid OERN (at least in most cases) +:) - **Side note:** it may have a certain charm to replace `"If Not IsError(...) Then` by the positive condition check `If IsNumeric(...) Then` emphasizing also the fact that a numeric result is attended. fyi Another way to use [`Application.Match()` to compare columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963224/compare-column-a-and-b-and-create-new-column-that-contains-values-that-only-exis/66967234#66967234)