# Compare column A and B and create new column that contains values that only exist in column A

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, office365

There are a few questions that ask something similar but not the exact thing.

I have two columns `X` and `Y`. `Y` contains only values that exist in `X`. I want to create a column `Z` that has all the values that exist only in `X`.

- `X` and `Y` can contain duplicate data as shown in the example
- `X` exists in `sheet1` whilst `Y and Z` exist in `sheet2`

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | c | a |
| b | e | b |
| b | d |  |
| c | e |  |
| d |  |  |
| e |  |  |

So far, I recorded a macro so naturally the code is super slow, despite my best efforts to clean it up. I won't post the whole code because it's quite messy but essentially I've

1. Used the `unique()` function to create two columns that contain the unique values of `X` and `Y` respectively.
2. Used `vlookup()` to create an adjacent column to the two I just created that returns an empty string
   if the adjacent unique `X` value exists in the unique `Y` column else returning the `X` value. This part is horribly slow. I created the formula in one cell then pasted it down.

```
Range("U2").Formula2R1C1 = "=UNIQUE('1.HoldingCart'!C[-18])"
Range("V2").Formula2R1C1 = "=UNIQUE(C[-19])"
Range("W3").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-2], C[-1], 1, FALSE)), RC[-2], """")"
Range("W3").Copy
Range("W3:W" & Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

[image]

3. Filtered out all the empty strings on the `vlookup()` column. Copied the actual values. Got rid of the filter. Deleted everything and then pasted the copied data thus creating column `Z`.

```
' Get the discrepancies
ActiveSheet.Range("$W:$W").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
Range("W2:W" & Cells(Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
Range("X2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _:=False, Transpose:=False

' Clean the sheet
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("U2:W" & Cells(Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents

' Paste the discrepancies
Range("X2:X" & Cells(Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row).Cut
Range("U2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Sorry you just had to read that horrible code. I'm happy to throw all that away. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For your information, if you would use a formula, you can simply use `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A6,COUNTIF(B1:B4,A1:A6)=0))`

Comment: I can't be sure of how the size of Column A and B and I also don't want the header. So instead of using `A1:A6` and `B1:B4` can I do something like `A2: A End` and `B2:B End`?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse, you'd want to find the last used rows of these columns.

Comment: To find the last used row in a column, you can use a code like this:
fRow = worksheet.Cells(worksheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

This will get the last row for column 1/A, and store the result to fRow. Try utilizing it in your code.. :)

Comment: I know how to find the last row in VBA, but not how to find it within a cell formula. I.e. I don't know how to use it for @jvdV's solution.

Comment: For reference, I'm pasting in Column A and B from other spreadsheets every day and I want this list of unique items to come up automatically.

Comment: Do you mean something without VBA? If so, maybe try: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)),COUNTIF(B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",B:B)),A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)))=0))`

Comment: Wow... you are a wizard. Thank you. How can I accept your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you do not mind to let go of VBA, but are willing to use a formula instead. With microsoft365, you can use:

[image]

Formula in `C2`

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)),COUNTIF(B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("ZZZ",B:B)),A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",A:A)))=0))
```

---

If you do want to go through VBA, then maybe use a Dictionary. A crude example could be:

```
Sub Test()

Dim LrA As Long, LrB As Long, x As Long
Dim arrA As Variant, arrB As Variant
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    
    'Get last used rows
    LrA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LrB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Initialize arrays
    arrA = .Range("A2:A" & LrA).Value
    arrB = .Range("B2:B" & LrB).Value
    
    'Run over arrA and fill Dictionary
    For x = LBound(arrA) To UBound(arrA)
        dict(arrA(x, 1)) = 1
    Next
    
    'Run over arrB and remove from Dictionary
    For x = LBound(arrB) To UBound(arrB)
        If dict.Exists(arrB(x, 1)) Then dict.Remove arrB(x, 1)
    Next
    
    'Pull remainder from dictionary
    .Cells(2, 3).Resize(dict.Count).Value = dict.Keys
    
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Do you think it's possible to do it an even faster way? Either using VBA or Formula?

Comment: @Mistakamikaze, yeah VBA may be a faster way, for example using a dictionary.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to? I am really horrible with VBA

Comment: @Mistakamikaze, I added a sample I pieced together.

Comment: Nice & helpful +:) - fyi Posted a relatively short dynamic *udf* benefitting from the newer dynamic features of version 365.

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative via user defined function `Unique2()` (vs. MS 365)**

Benefitting from the new dynamic features of MS 365 you can combine the new (worksheet) function

- `Unique()` *(available since version 365)*

with

- `Application.Match()`  *(undocumented **simultaneous!** comparison of two arrays) plus
- a negative filtering via `VBA.Filter()` of already existant items to be deleted. -  These are identified via `IsNumeric()` as they return any found positions within the 2nd array (whereas the actually searched *uniques* would return an error value, which gets ignored by `IsNumeric`)

```
Function UNIQUE2(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range)
Dim x:   x = Application.Unique(rng1)
Dim y:   y = rng2
Dim tmp: tmp = Application.Transpose(Application.Match(x, y, 0))
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp)
    tmp(i) = IIf(IsNumeric(tmp(i)), "DELETE", x(i, 1))
Next
UNIQUE2 = Application.Transpose(Filter(tmp, "DELETE", False))
End Function
```

**Example call via formula input**

Enter the following dynamic (udf) formula e.g. into cell `Z1` to get the whole spill range filled:

```
    =UNIQUE2(X1:X6,Y1:Y4)
```

[image: Spill range]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 1):

### Write Unique Column

[image]

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- [`Download`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qkX6O1wow6XhiAD3cIGp1Gi4ykJ7Zq-6/view?usp=sharing) a copy of the workbook from `Google Drive` (down arrow at the top-right)

```vb
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the unique values from the Source Column, that are not
'               found in the Lookup Column, to the Destination Column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub writeUniqueColumn()
    Const ProcName As String = "writeUniqueColumn"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirst As String = "A2"
    Const lName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const lFirst As String = "A2"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirst As String = "B2"
    
    Dim isDataFound As Boolean
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirst)
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = getUniqueColumn(sCell)
    If IsEmpty(sData) Then GoTo ProcExit
    
    Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = wb.Worksheets(lName).Range(lFirst)
    Dim lData As Variant: lData = getUniqueColumn(lCell)
    If IsEmpty(lData) Then GoTo ProcExit
    
    Dim Indexes As Variant: Indexes = Application.Match(sData, lData, 0)
    Dim sCount As Long: sCount = UBound(sData, 1)
    Dim dCount As Long: dCount = sCount - Application.Count(Indexes)
    
    If dCount = 0 Then GoTo ProcExit
        
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To dCount, 1 To 1)
    Dim s As Long, d As Long
    For s = 1 To sCount
        If IsError(Indexes(s, 1)) Then
            d = d + 1
            dData(d, 1) = sData(s, 1)
        End If
    Next s
    
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirst)
    With dCell
        .Resize(dCount).Value = dData
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - dCount + 1) _
            .Offset(dCount).ClearContents
    End With
    
    isDataFound = True

ProcExit:
    
    If isDataFound Then
        If dCount = 1 Then
            MsgBox "Found 1 unique value.", vbInformation, "Unique"
        Else
            MsgBox "Found " & dCount & " unique values.", _
                vbInformation, "Unique"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "No unique values found", vbExclamation, "No Data"
    End If
    
    Exit Sub

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the unique values from a one-column range
'               to a 2D one-based array, excluding error and blank values.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function getUniqueColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range, _
    Optional ByVal Horizontal As Boolean = False) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "getUniqueColumn"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If Not FirstCell Is Nothing Then
        Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = fCell.Resize(fCell.Worksheet.Rows.Count - fCell.Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If Not lCell Is Nothing Then
            Dim rg As Range: Set rg = fCell.Resize(lCell.Row - fCell.Row + 1)
            Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
            Dim Data As Variant
            If rCount = 1 Then
                ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
            Else
                Data = rg.Value
            End If
            Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
            Dim Key As Variant
            Dim n As Long
            For n = 1 To rCount
                Key = Data(n, 1)
                If Not IsError(Key) Then
                    If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                        dict(Key) = Empty
                    End If
                End If
            Next n
            If dict.Count > 0 Then
                n = 0
                If Horizontal Then
                    ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To dict.Count)
                    For Each Key In dict.Keys
                        n = n + 1
                        Data(1, n) = Key
                    Next Key
                Else
                    ReDim Data(1 To dict.Count, 1 To 1)
                    For Each Key In dict.Keys
                        n = n + 1
                        Data(n, 1) = Key
                    Next Key
                End If
                getUniqueColumn = Data
            End If
        End If
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer!